# Ubuntu 14.04 gdm with multiple X servers doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, gdm

I'm trying to launch 4 X servers with `gdm` on my fresh Ubuntu 14.04.

`/etc/gdm/custom.conf`

```
[debug]
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
Enable = true
Gestures = true

[servers]
0 = Standard vt7
1 = Standard vt8
2 = Standard vt9
3 = Standard vt10
```

The debug flag is working well. I'm trying to disable/enable, seems good.

```
/var/log/syslog:31718:Apr 23 02:05:57 bt gdm-simple-slave[3255]: GdmServer: Starting X server process: /usr/bin/X :0 -background none -verbose -logverbose 7 -core -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-Kt5Dw5/database -seat seat0 -nolisten tcp vt7
/var/log/syslog:31719:Apr 23 02:05:57 bt gdm-simple-slave[3260]: GdmServer: Opening logfile for server /var/log/gdm/:0.log
/var/log/syslog:31720:Apr 23 02:05:57 bt gdm-simple-slave[3255]: GdmServer: Started X server process 3260 - waiting for READY
/var/log/syslog:31721:Apr 23 02:05:57 bt gdm-simple-slave[3255]: GdmSimpleSlave: Started X server
/var/log/syslog:31722:Apr 23 02:05:58 bt gdm-simple-slave[3255]: GdmServer: Got USR1 from X server - emitting READY
/var/log/syslog:31723:Apr 23 02:05:58 bt gdm-simple-slave[3255]: GdmSlave: Server is ready - opening display :0
/var/log/syslog:31724:Apr 23 02:05:58 bt gdm-simple-slave[3255]: GdmSlave: Connected to display :0
```

But there is nothing in syslog about starting second or third X server. No information about `vt8` or `vt9` or `vt10`, only `vt7`.

What with X servers? Is it my syntax mistake?

And why doesn't debug show anything about multiple X servers?

Comment: With kdm, I simply add similar directives to kdmrc, and everything works. Why gdm? Because it is native to gnome. Why 4 X? There is security reason.